# How to apply fast scroll using PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, layout, setting

I'm using **ListPreference** within PreferenceActivity. With this widget, is it possible to apply a fast scrolling to it? If yes, how can I do it?

Right now, I'm stuck with this screen, without fastscroll:
[image]

My .XML source is:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/label_settingfirstcategory" android:key="first_category">
    <ListPreference 
        android:key="updates_interval"
        android:title="@string/label_countrycode"
        android:summary="@string/label_countrycodesummary"
        android:entries="@array/countrycode"
        android:entryValues="@array/countrycode"

    />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And my activity/java source is:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in easy way. Default `ListPreference` does not allow fast scrolling.

You can create you own `ListPreferenceWithFastScrolling`, extend it from `DialogPreference` and override `showDialog` method with your custom dialog, where you can implement everything you want.

Comment: Hi Jin. Thanks for the answer! Looks like you are correct about this feature missing in ListPreference.